# Add fees based on custom selected options in WooCommerce Cart page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, session-variables

I've added some checkboxes to my cart page which give the customers the opportunity to add extra items to their order.

This is based on [Custom checkbox that adds a fee in WooCommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251461/custom-checkbox-that-adds-a-fee-in-woocommerce-cart-page/64257496#64257496) answer code.

The last checkbox doubles needs to double the price of the product (which it's doing) but also the Stall Added price needs to double (become £20).

Cart page with relevant boxes checked:

[image]

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    Add to cart page 
\*------------------------------------*/


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'add_extras_title', 20 );

function add_extras_title(){
    
    if( current_user_can( 'stallholder') ) {

        echo '<table><tr class="installment-section">
        <h3>'.__("Add Extras").'</h3></tr></table>';
               
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    
}


/* Add Stall */

// Display the checkout field in cart page totals section
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'display_priority_fee_checkbox_field', 20 );

function display_priority_fee_checkbox_field(){
    
    if( current_user_can( 'stallholder') ) {

        echo '<table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive"><tr class="installment-section">
        <th>'.__("Add Stall").'</th><td>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'priority_fee', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __(' £10.00'),
        ), WC()->session->get('priority_fee') ? '1' : '' );

        echo '</td></tr>';
               
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    
}

// Remove "(optional)" text from the field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_txt_from_priority_fee_checkbox', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_txt_from_priority_fee_checkbox( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'priority_fee' === $key ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// jQuery :: Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'priority_fee_js_script' );
function priority_fee_js_script() {
    // On Order received page, remove the wc session variable if it exist
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')
        && WC()->session->__isset('priority_fee') ) :

        WC()->session->__unset('priority_fee');

    // On Cart page: jQuert script
    elseif ( is_cart() ) :

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var c = 'input[name=priority_fee]';

        $(document.body).on( 'click change', c, function(){
            console.log('click');
            var fee = $(c).is(':checked') ? '1' : '';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'priority_fee',
                    'priority_fee': fee,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart');
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_priority_fee', 'priority_fee_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_priority_fee', 'priority_fee_ajax_receiver' );
function priority_fee_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['priority_fee']) ) {
        $priority_fee = $_POST['priority_fee'] ? true : false;
        // Set to a WC Session variable
        WC()->session->set('priority_fee', $priority_fee );

        echo $priority_fee ? '1' : '0';
        die();
    }
}

// Add a custom calculated fee conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'set_priority_fee' );
function set_priority_fee( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;
            
        if ( WC()->session->get('priority_fee') && isset($_GET['double_pitch']) && $_GET['double_pitch'] == "1")  {
            $stall  = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
            $fee_label   = sprintf( __( "Stall Added" ) );
            $fee_amount  = 20 * $item_count;
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
        }
        
        if ( WC()->session->get('priority_fee') ) {
        $item_count  = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        $fee_label   = sprintf( __( "Stall Added" ) );
        $fee_amount  = 10 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
        
    
    }

}


/* Add Power */

// Display the checkout field in cart page totals section
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'display_power_checkbox_field', 20 );
function display_power_checkbox_field(){
    
    if( current_user_can( 'stallholder') && current_user_can('hot_food')  ) {

        echo '<tr class="installment-section">
            <th>'.__("Add Power").'</th><td>';

            woocommerce_form_field( 'power_16', array(
                'type'          => 'checkbox',
                'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
                'label'         => __(' £10.00 (16v Supply)'),
            ), WC()->session->get('power_16') ? '1' : '' );
                
            woocommerce_form_field( 'power_32', array(
                'type'          => 'checkbox',
                'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
                'label'         => __(' £20.00 (32v Supply)'),
            ), WC()->session->get('power_32') ? '1' : '' );
            
        echo '</td></tr>';
               
    }
   
    
    else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    
}


// Remove "(optional)" text from the field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_txt_from_power_checkbox', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_txt_from_power_checkbox( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'power_16' === $key ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    if( 'power_32' === $key ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}




// jQuery :: Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'power_js_script' );
function power_js_script() {
    // On Order received page, remove the wc session variable if it exist
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')
        && WC()->session->__isset('power_16') ) :

        WC()->session->__unset('power_16');
    
    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')
        && WC()->session->__isset('power_32') ) :

        WC()->session->__unset('power_32');

    // On Cart page: jQuert script
    elseif ( is_cart() ) :

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var c = 'input[name=power_16]';

        $(document.body).on( 'click change', c, function(){
            console.log('click');
            var fee = $(c).is(':checked') ? '1' : '';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'power_16',
                    'power_16': fee,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart');
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var c = 'input[name=power_32]';

        $(document.body).on( 'click change', c, function(){
            console.log('click');
            var fee = $(c).is(':checked') ? '1' : '';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'power_32',
                    'power_32': fee,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart');
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_power_16', 'power_16_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_power_16', 'power_16_ajax_receiver' );
function power_16_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['power_16']) ) {
        $power_16 = $_POST['power_16'] ? true : false;
        // Set to a WC Session variable
        WC()->session->set('power_16', $power_16 );

        echo $power_16 ? '1' : '0';
        die();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_power_32', 'power_32_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_power_32', 'power_32_ajax_receiver' );
function power_32_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['power_32']) ) {
        $power_32 = $_POST['power_32'] ? true : false;
        // Set to a WC Session variable
        WC()->session->set('power_32', $power_32 );

        echo $power_32 ? '1' : '0';
        die();
    }
}

// Add a custom calculated fee conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'set_power' );
function set_power( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    if ( WC()->session->get('power_16') ) {
        $item_count  = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        $fee_label   = sprintf( __( "16v Supply Added" ) );
        $fee_amount  = 10 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }
    if ( WC()->session->get('power_32') ) {
        $item_count  = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        $fee_label   = sprintf( __( "32v Supply Added" ) );
        $fee_amount  = 20 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }
}


/* Double Pitch*/

// Display the checkout field in cart page totals section

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'display_double_pitch_checkbox_field', 20 );
function display_double_pitch_checkbox_field(){
    
    if( current_user_can( 'stallholder') ) {

echo '<tr class="installment-section">
    <th>'.__("Double Pitch").'</th><td>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'double_pitch', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __(' x2'),
    ), WC()->session->get('double_pitch') ? '1' : '' );

    echo '</td></tr></table>';
               
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    
}



// Remove "(optional)" text from the field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_txt_from_double_pitch_checkbox', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_txt_from_double_pitch_checkbox( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'double_pitch' === $key ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// jQuery :: Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'double_pitch_js_script' );
function double_pitch_js_script() {
    // On Order received page, remove the wc session variable if it exist
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')
        && WC()->session->__isset('double_pitch') ) :

        WC()->session->__unset('double_pitch');

    // On Cart page: jQuert script
    elseif ( is_cart() ) :

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var c = 'input[name=double_pitch]';

        $(document.body).on( 'click change', c, function(){
            console.log('click');
            var fee = $(c).is(':checked') ? '1' : '';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'double_pitch',
                    'double_pitch': fee,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart');
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_double_pitch', 'double_pitch_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_double_pitch', 'double_pitch_ajax_receiver' );
function double_pitch_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['double_pitch']) ) {
        $double_pitch = $_POST['double_pitch'] ? true : false;
        // Set to a WC Session variable
        WC()->session->set('double_pitch', $double_pitch );

        echo $double_pitch ? '1' : '0';
        die();
    }
}

// Add a custom calculated fee conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'set_double_pitch' );
function set_double_pitch( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

  if ( WC()->session->get('double_pitch') ) {
        $item_count  = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
        $fee_label   = __( "Double Pitch" ) ;
        $fee_amount  = 1 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }

}
```

I've tried isset in many different ways but can not figure it out.

What I need to happen is for the Stall added to x2 (£20) when 'Double Pitch' is checked and return to £10 if unchecked.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Allow swapping "Power" checkboxes, avoiding getting both checkboxes selected…

I have completely revised, optimized and compacted your code, allowing "Double Pitch" option to double "Stall" fee amount when selected.

```php
// Add custom input checkbox fields in cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'display_custom_fields_before_cart_totals', 20 );
function display_custom_fields_before_cart_totals(){
    if( current_user_can( 'stallholder') ) {
        echo '<h3>'.__("Add Extras").'</h3>
        <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive add-extras">';
        
        // 1) Add Stall
        echo '<tr class="stall-section">
        <th>'.__("Add Stall").'</th>
        <td>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'stall', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __(' £10.00'),
        ), WC()->session->get('stall') );

        echo '</td></tr>';

        // 2) Add Power
        if( current_user_can('hot_food') ) {
            echo '<tr class="power-section">
            <th>'.__("Add Power").'</th>
            <td>';

            woocommerce_form_field( 'power_16', array(
                'type'          => 'checkbox',
                'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
                'label'         => __(' £10.00 (16v Supply)'),
            ), WC()->session->get('power_16') );
                
            woocommerce_form_field( 'power_32', array(
                'type'          => 'checkbox',
                'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
                'label'         => __(' £20.00 (32v Supply)'),
            ), WC()->session->get('power_32') );
            
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }

        // 3) Add Double Pitch
        echo '<tr class="2x-pitch-section">
        <th>'.__("Double Pitch").'</th><td>';
    
        woocommerce_form_field( '2x_pitch', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __(' x2'),
        ), WC()->session->get('2x_pitch') );
    
        echo '</td></tr></table>';
    } 
}

// Remove "(optional)" text from custom fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_txt_from_custom_fields', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_txt_from_custom_fields( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if( ! is_cart() ) return $field;

    // Here below, define your custom field keys
    $fields   = array('stall', 'power_16', 'power_32', '2x_pitch');

    if( in_array($key, $fields) ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field    = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    } 
    return $field;
}

// jQuery :: Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_cart_extras_js' );
function add_cart_extras_js() {
    // On Order received page, remove custom wc session variables if they exist
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        foreach ( array('stall', 'power_16', 'power_32', '2x_pitch') as $key ) {
            if ( WC()->session->__isset($key) ) {
                WC()->session->__unset($key);
            }
        }
    // On Cart page: jQuery script
    } elseif ( is_cart() ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        const fields = 'input[name=stall],input[name=power_16],input[name=power_32],input[name=2x_pitch]';

        $(document.body).on( 'change', fields, function(){
            const fieldKey = $(this).prop('id'),
                  checked  = $(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';

            if ( fieldKey === 'power_16' && $(this).prop('checked') && $('input[name=power_32]').prop('checked') ) {
                $('input[name=power_32]').prop('checked', false);
            } else if ( fieldKey === 'power_32' && $(this).prop('checked') && $('input[name=power_16]').prop('checked') ) {
                $('input[name=power_16]').prop('checked', false);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action':      'setting_up_extras',
                    'field_key':   fieldKey,
                    'field_value': checked,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart');
                    console.log(response); // For testing (to be removed)
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}

// Get Ajax request and saving selected options to WC session variables
add_action( 'wp_ajax_setting_up_extras', 'setting_up_selected_extras_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_setting_up_extras', 'setting_up_selected_extras_ajax_receiver' );
function setting_up_selected_extras_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['field_key']) && isset($_POST['field_value']) ) {
        $key   = esc_attr($_POST['field_key']);
        $value = boolval($_POST['field_value']);

        WC()->session->set($key, $value);

        if ( $key === 'power_16' && $value && WC()->session->get('power_32') ) {
            WC()->session->set('power_32', false);
        } elseif ( $key === 'power_32' && $value && WC()->session->get('power_16') ) {
            WC()->session->set('power_16', false);
        }
        wp_die(json_encode([$key => $value]));
    } else {
        wp_die('Something went wrong');
    }
}

// Add a custom calculated fee conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_selected_extras_fees' );
function add_selected_extras_fees( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    $item_count  = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
            
    if ( WC()->session->get('stall') )  {
        $fee_label   = __( "Stall Added", "woocommerce" );
        $fee_amount  = 10 * $item_count;
        $fee_amount  = WC()->session->get('2x_pitch') ? $fee_amount * 2 : $fee_amount;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }

    if ( WC()->session->get('power_16') ) {
        $fee_label   = __( "16v Supply Added", "woocommerce" );
        $fee_amount  = 10 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }

    if ( WC()->session->get('power_32') ) {
        $fee_label   = __( "32v Supply Added", "woocommerce" );
        $fee_amount  = 20 * $item_count;
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }

    if ( WC()->session->get('2x_pitch') ) {
        $fee_label   = __( "Double Pitch", "woocommerce" ) ;
        $fee_amount  = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
        $cart->add_fee( $fee_label, $fee_amount, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks. Had to tweak user visibility for the power section but it worked like a dream. I've since been informed that only one of the power boxes can be checked. So they can only have a 16v or 32v power supply. Any chance you could help with this?

Comment: I'll try. See new image also. There are two checkboxes under 'Add Power' (16v & 32v). If one is checked then the other should be unchecked. Both boxes cannot be checked at the same time. User only has the option of one or the other.