# Display a checkbox, that adds a fee but only visable when delivery option is selected Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [Display a checkbox that add a fee in Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613334/display-a-checkbox-that-add-a-fee-in-woocommerce-checkout-page/57613912#57613912) answer code, that displays a checkbox in checkout page that adds a fee when checked.

I would like to get this checkbox visible only when 'Express Delivery' is selected.  If any other delivery option (Standard Delivery, Local Pick up) is selected then the checkbox should be hidden.

Any ideas would be amazing and thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I would guess that a woocommerce expert would solve this problem in less than a minute.

Comment: If you don't provide in your question the correct shipping rate id for "Express Delivery" nobody can really help you…

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec  you are correct, sorry it was late when i was adding this, sorry..  Im using a plugin to allow for table rate shipping and the id for this is jem_table_rate_26_express-delivery.  The Id for Standard delivery is 'flat_rate:19' and the id for local pickup is 'local_pickup:20'  However my shipping works on postcodes so I would need this to work for each of my 6 zones.

Comment: @Justin Please don't add in your question an existing answer code if you don't make real changes to it, the link to the answer code is enough.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Oh man!! sorry, can you tell im a newbie on this...hahah!